# When I use TTS, occur setLanguage failed on android

Tags: android

I use TTS (Text to speech) but my device not speak voice.

```
TtsEngine::setLanguage called with unsupported language
setLanguage(kor, KOR,) failed
```

I think my device not supported korean language.

how to install korean language pack?

my source.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

   //create TTS
   tts = new TextToSpeech(this, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
       @Override
       public void onInit(int i) {

          if (i != ERROR) {
              tts.setLanguage(Locale.KOREAN);
          }
          else {
          }
       }
    });

    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            tts.speak(editText.getText().toString(), TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
        }
    });
 }
```

How to speak on my android device ?

thanks:..

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       tts = new TextToSpeech(this, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
           @Override
           public void onInit(int status) {
              if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS ) {

{
        int result = tts.setLanguage(Locale.getDefault());
        System.out.println ( "Result : " + result  + " " + Locale.getDefault().getLanguage() );

        if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA
                || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) 
        {
            Toast.makeText( this , "Please Set your Language to English US.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
        }
        else
        {
                  tts.setLanguage(Locale.KOREAN);//remove this line
                  tts.setLanguage(new Locale("ko_KR"));//add this line
                  tts.speak( "hey",TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null );
        }                            
           }
        });
        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                tts.speak(editText.getText().toString(), TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
            }
        });
```

Comment: first, my galaxy s8 + device  , success work. but another my device `01-08 14:20:58.016 5480-24692/com.svox.pico E/SVOX Pico Engine: TtsEngine::setLanguage called with unsupported language
01-08 14:20:58.016 5480-24692/com.svox.pico E/CompatTtsService: setLanguage(kor,KOR,) failed`

Comment: i update the code, check your device supported or not Korean language, debug the app.

Comment: I think my device not support korean language, and english language, how to install language pack?

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer: Try to turn the WIFI on**

I had the same problem.

If you filter the word "TTS" in the logcat, you can see that the device is trying to download the locale. So, if you turn on Wifi, your problem should be solved. I'm looking for a solution to load the Locale locally on the device to avoid downloading it over the Internet.